# How to model all the permutations of pointer/dereferencing syntax from C or Rust in a different programming language syntax?

Tags: pointers, dereference

I am working on a custom programming language with minimal syntax, and wondering how I can properly account for and handle the various pointer/dereferencing syntax in C or Rust.

Say that every variable is by default a "pointer" type, when you simply write a variable.

```
save x, 10
```

The "pointer" type has 2 properties (at least, so far):

```
x      # the pointer
x.bond # the actual value
x.slot # the memory address
```

So I try and look at C examples (not having much practical experience with C and Rust beyond the basics):

```
// C
int a = 10;
int &b = a; // Value of b will be = 10. Changing "b" will cause "a" to change.

# try it in custom lang
save a, 10
# assign the address of b to the address of a
save b.slot, a.slot
# now changing b will change a
save b, 20

// C
int *p = &a;

# custom lang
# set the value of p to the address of a? is that correct?
save p.bond, a.slot
p.bond.bond # the value 10 of a? same as **p?
```

Basically I am wondering what are all the main operations I can do on pointers, using this different style of syntax?

```
save a, 10
# int &b = a;
save b.slot, a.slot
# int *p = &a;
save p.bond, a.slot
# now what about these other combinations?
save b.slot, a      # is this possible, what would this do?
save b.slot, a.bond # what would this do?
save b.bond, a      # is this even possible?
save b.bond, a.bond # what about this?
                    # did I miss any combinations/permutations?
save b, a
save b, a.slot
save b, a.bond
```

What I am trying to wrap my head around is all of the permutations of how to pass the values/pointers/addresses around. It's not quite clear to me how many exact cases there are in C or Rust, but I've tried to outline what I am imagining in that last set of examples.

```
# b's address is a's address
save b.slot, a.slot

# b's address is a as a pointer? seems incorrect or invalid?
save b.slot, a      

# b's address is a's value? seems correct
save b.slot, a.bond

# b's value is a's address
save b.bond, a.slot 

# b's value is a as a pointer? seems incorrect or invalid?
save b.bond, a      

# b's value is a's value? seems correct
save b.bond, a.bond 

# but what about these last cases then, what do they mean?
save b, a
save b, a.slot
save b, a.bond
```

Basically trying to figure out how exactly to translate C or Rust pointer syntax/functionality to a different language syntax.

Doesn't have to be 100% exact answer, just close enough as to how to translate these C/Rust-style pointer/dereferencing permutations into a more verbose syntax.

Comment: It is confusion that you have both `x` (pointer) and `x.slot` (address). There doesn't seem to be a difference in the concept. Somehow you want to distinguish such that `x` can have `x.bond`, but then in your examples you seem to suggest there is also `x.slot.bond` ... which would be the same thing. That begs the question: what is the difference between `x` and `x.slot`?

Comment: @trincot I guess that's partly where I get confused, maybe let's assume that `x` is an alias to `x.slot`? I was thinking the pointer _has a_ memory address, which is x.slot (the address itself, an integer), but maybe I'm wrong. Feel free to play with the ideas to simply try and capture an API for the few different pieces.

Comment: OK, but then `save a, 10` should have the same effect as `save a.slot, 10`